# webrtc store video and audio file separately

Tags: blob, webrtc, getusermedia

I am want to store video with audio and and only audio file separately, however i am able to save video with audio, how do i save only audio as a 2nd file, below is js code

```
var listOfFilesUploaded = [];
function uploadToServer(recordRTC, callback) {
var blob = recordRTC instanceof Blob ? recordRTC : recordRTC.blob;
var fileType = blob.type.split('/')[0] || 'audio';
var fileName = (Math.random() * 1000).toString().replace('.', '');

if (fileType === 'audio') {
    fileName += '.' + (!!navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? 'ogg' : 'wav');
} else {
    fileName += '.webm';
}
// create FormData
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);

callback('Uploading ' + fileType + ' recording to server.');

makeXMLHttpRequest('save.php', formData, function(progress) {
    if (progress !== 'upload-ended') {
        callback(progress);
        return;
    }
```

Requirements:
1. Store Video along with the voice - which is working through below code
2. Store Audio file separately - Not able to figure out how to do it through below code.